# How can i print on new lines?

Tags: python, list, function

How can i print my output from this function and each boolean to be on new line.

```
def is_palindrome(n):
    return str(n) == str(n)[::-1]


numbers = list(map(int, input().split(', ')))
palindrome_status = [is_palindrome(n) for n in numbers]

print(palindrome_status)
```

Output:

```
[False, True, False, True]
```

Expecting:

```
False
True
False
True
```

Comment: You can do something like `print(*palindrome_status, sep='\n')` to put a new line between each item. If you don't need the list, it's not clear why you are using a list comprehension. Just loop and print instead.

Comment: Iterate over the list and print each item separately.  What is the difficulty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be print it one by one:

```
[print(is_palindrome(n)) for n in numbers]
```

**BUT**

List comprehesion **shouldn't be used** with side effect functions, to have it clean you should use normal loop:

```
for n in numbers:
    print(is_palindrome(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert boolean to string, then insert newlines.

```
print("\n".join(map(str, palindrome_status)))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. Use a for loop to iterate over the elements and then print

> for val in palindrome_status: 
> print(val)

2. Use the print separator for newlines while unpacking the list

> print(*palindrome_status, sep='\n')